# Bitlocker & Win7 on one partition, Ubuntu & encryption on another, same drive

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, encryption

I have a laptop with a 64GB SSD and 1TB regular drive.

The 64GB SSD has Win7 installed on it.
The 1TB drive is partitioned into 500GB as NTFS, 480GB for Ubuntu /, and the rest for Ubuntu swap.

For whatever reason, Ubuntu can't see the SSD, so to choose my OS at boot I just change the drive boot order. I can live with this.

I want to encrypt the Win7 stuff (SSD + half the 1TB) with Bitlocker. I also want to encrypt the Ubuntu partitions with whatever is appropriate.

Never having done this before, my concern is that using two schemes on the same drive will hose the whole arrangement.

Can this be safely done?

Answer (score 3):

> Can this be safely done?

Yes.

A little background. Both operating systems require one unencrypted partition for booting.
Windows bitlocker has already created these partitions on your SSD:

- System reserved partition (unencrypted)
- Main partition (`C:\`) (encrypted)

An MBR partition table can contain either *four primary partitions* **or** *three primary partitions* and an *extended partition*. Accessing one partition does not affect the others (*for your purposes*).

So for your HDD, you should have:

- your current NTFS partition
- unencrypted Ubuntu boot partition
- LUKS encrypted Ubuntu root partition

These can all be primary partitions. If you create a swap, I recommend putting it on an extended partition, in case you need more partitions in the future. Do be aware though, that an unencrypted swap partition may be a security risk.

`gparted` is a good tool for both viewing and editing partitions. The installer can also create the most common partition schemes for you during installation.